# Django+django-filebrowser+TinyMCE

Tags: django, tinymce, django-filebrowser

I added TinyMCE (directly, not django-tinymce) and django-filebrowser to django admin. It works, except one thing:
Then I click File Browse button on Tiny "add picture" menu, I get Page not found (404), because I don't understand what means this string in Tiny options:

```
var managerURL = window.location.toString()
        + 'media/upload/?type=' + type;
```

Full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tinyDjangoBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
var managerURL = window.location.toString()
        + 'media/upload/?type=' + type;

tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    file: managerURL,
    title: 'Pic',
    width: 800,
    height: 450,
    resizable: 'yes',
    inline: 'yes',
    close_previous: 'no',
    popup_css : false
}, {
    window: win,
    input: field_name
});

return false;
}
   tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    skin : "bootstrap",
            plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
            extended_valid_elements : 'script[type|src],iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder],div[*],p[*],object[width|height|classid|codebase|embed|param],param[name|value],embed[param|src|type|width|height|flashvars|wmode]',
    media_strict: false,
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,
            file_browser_callback: 'tinyDjangoBrowser',
    relative_urls : "false",
    remove_script_host : false,
    convert_urls : false
  });
</script>
```

Tell me please, how it should be in my case?

One more thing: need I connect tiny_mce_popup.js? Sorry for my bad english. Thx!

Comment: can you log this to your console? window.location.toString()
        + 'media/upload/?type=' + type . what url do you get?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auto/blogmain/2/media/upload/?type=image I know what it's absolutely wrong, but I don't understand what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found! In my case it should be

```
var managerURL = '/admin/filebrowser/browse/?pop=2'
```